# How do I bind a WinForms DataGridView control to a SQL Server database

Tags: data-binding, datagridview

I am a .NET noob who is trying for figure out how to bind a grid control to a SQL Server database so that when rows are inserted, updated or deleted from the grid, they are also inserted, updated or deleted from the database. C#, .NET 3.5, VS2008 SP1

Warren

Answer (score 0):

Drag the control on the form. Then click the small arrow at the top right corner of the DataGridView to open up a menu. Select Choose your source, and select your database or dataset. Then on the same menu, you can choose whether to enable Adding, Edit, Deleting, or Reordering of columns.