# GridView doesn't show data

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

```
private void fill()
{
  adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM LibraryInfo WHERE First_Name='"+LoginName+"'", cn);      
  //LoginName is a string variable for displaying users info after the login          
  ds.Clear();
  adptr.Fill(ds);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

After the database updated, GridView didn't show data.

Comment: remove this line dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
and include more details so that we can help you....

Comment: My login name is... `MrSQLInjection'); DROP TABLE LibraryInfo;--` P.s. do not use my name ;)

Comment: The only piece the OP is missing is `dataGridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: Please bind the data using .DataBind()

Comment: before everybody write for gridView.DataBind(), ask if this is winform or asp.net, because in winform you don't need DataBind()! Is this winform or asp.net application ?

Comment: yes, it's windows form.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the [GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097489/3436942)?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) article on the `DataBind` Property.

---

## ASP EXAMPLE

---

```
 void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // This example uses Microsoft SQL Server and connects
    // to the Northwind sample database. The data source needs
    // to be bound to the GridView control only when the 
    // page is first loaded. Thereafter, the values are
    // stored in view state.                      
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      // Declare the query string.
      String queryString = 
        "Select [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [Address], [City], [PostalCode], [Country] From [Customers]";

      // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
      // to the GridView control.
      DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
      if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      {
        AuthorsGridView.DataSource = ds;
        AuthorsGridView.DataBind();
      }
      else
      {
        Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";
      }

    }     

  }

  DataSet GetData(String queryString)
  {

    // Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;      

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
      // Connect to the database and run the query.
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);        
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

      // Fill the DataSet.
      adapter.Fill(ds);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

      // The connection failed. Display an error message.
      Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";

    }

    return ds;

  }
```

This snippet shows you how to (a) bind your dataset to a gridview, by assigning it using the Databind method.

The site also says:

> Use the DataBind() method to bind data from a data source to the GridView control. This method resolves all data-binding expressions in the active template of the control.

**SOLUTION**

I would like to reference the line saying:

```
 AuthorsGridView.DataBind();
```

which actually **binds** the data to the control.

**SIDE NOTE**

To protect yourself from SQLi, you should read up on [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx), and not direct concatenation.

---

## WINFORM EXAMPLE

---

Tutorial was found: [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database)

```
//create the connection string
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\myDatabase.mdb";

//create the database query
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

//create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

//create a command builder
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

//create a DataTable to hold the query results
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

//fill the DataTable
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
```

Also:

```
//the DataGridView
DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView();

//BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

//set the BindingSource DataSource
bSource.DataSource = dTable;

//set the DataGridView DataSource
dgView.DataSource = bSource;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do with this answer?

Comment: show OP how to Bind the gridview, as stated in the question. I could also ask the same as to why you commented?

Comment: That's nicely written, but it only fits to asp.net. The OPs question is about winforms, which he pointed out (sadly!) to late...

Comment: I have asked for clarification under the Question, and hence will edit my answer (depending on response)

Answer (score 0):

Use are missing to call databind method here.Use following code :

```
 DataAdapter adapter=new DataAdapter(SqlCommand,SqlConn);
 DataTable tbl=new Datatable();
 adapter.Fill(tbl);
 GridView1.DataSource=tbl;
 GridView1.DataBind();//This line is missing in your code
```

try with this format?

Comment: there's an error in part of GridView1.DataBind();, it seems that it can't recoginize the .DataBind();